# Static and dynamic MFC linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

How should I link my program with MFC in Visual Studio 2010 if I want user could run my program without having Visual Studio and MFC libaray. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static linking is one way. Then you executable will contain everything, but be rather large.

Having the customers install the dynamic libraries is another. They can get them from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will find how to do the static linking. Very usefull answer.

Comment: Beware of the debug dlls. Make sure that you link against the release version otherwise your customer might run into problems. The debug version have some certain dependencies that implies that your client has VS2010 on his/her PC.

Comment: NP :) You might know the following, but thought could add something to it. Go to project property pages, then Configuration Properties, then General, then in the project defaults part you will see: Use of MFC. There you can set that. Before that you might want to make sure that you have selected "All Configurations" in the Configuration list at the top of the property pages, this you can avoid remembering to set for all of the configs.